# iOS call method of another class

Tags: ios, class, methods

I found similar questions on this site but not one that addresses the problem in a clear and basic way.

I have my ReadViewController.h and ReadViewController.m files along with my ChooseViewController.h and ChooseViewController.m files.

They both need to access the getProperties method which is currently in the ReadViewController.m file.

```
- (void) getProperties {
    NSLog(@"Start getProperties");
//SOME CODE
    NSLog(@"End getProperties");
}
```

Now ideally this will be in a third file called GeneralModel.m

Please give me a basic example of what code needs to be in the controller files for them to be able to call this method.

Comment: I think you wanna use Inheritance. You can implement in the GeneralModel.m and .h file the method - (void)getProperty. Then you can call ReadViewController *rvc... and then [rvc getProperties] without implementing the method in the ReadViewController. But dont forget to implement @interface ReadViewController: GeneralModel in the header of ReadViewController

Comment: You seem to lack basic knowledge how Objective-C (and programming in general) works. I suggest you take a look at a few "getting started" articles, e.g. http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: Yeah `AndreasLey` it may be true. But one thing here i would like to explain. if someone trying know something then we should give it +vely rather making some nonsense way.`sorry dude` ,here i am not pointing this word to you i am just pointing to whom made downVote to this Question.I simply thinks Today if someone has lack knowledge it does not mean that he  can't get that knowledge.....!!!!! in future we just really need to co-operate.i really hate to those who try to criticise...!!!!

Comment: @iOS-Deveoper I did not downvote. Also, I agree that we should try to help everyone here - which is why I posted a comment with a link to a site which nicely explains the basics of Objective-C, including an answer to this specific question. In the long run, both McGafter and contributors of SO will profit from him learning the very basics of ObjC. That's at least what I think.

Comment: @McGafter Yes, the point of this site is to gain knowledge. I was not my intention to discourage you. However, I assumed that you will run into a lot of similar questions in the near future. The link to the tutorial I've posted could maybe prevent that.

Comment: @AndreasLey i know dude , you did not downVote. here in that my First Comment i was not pointing to you...!!!!!.see i have already appreciate your comment. i have dropped my first comment to who downVoted `McGafter`'s Question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this method Going to be used in many places in Application then in this case you should treat it as Global method and try to put  this method in separate class may be type of `NSObject` Class.

```
  @interface Utility :NSobject

  - (void) getProperties
  @end

 @implementation Utility

 - (void) getProperties {
    NSLog(@"Start getProperties");
   //SOME CODE
    NSLog(@"End getProperties");
 }
 @end
```

Here Whenever you need that methods you just need to create the Object of `Utility` Class can access it easily wherever it needed.like

in `ReadViewController` just make object and access in this way

```
  Utility * obje = [Utility  alloc]init];

  [obje getProperties  ];
```

And One thing if you just talking about the App architecture ,Suppose you following the `MVC` in that Case you should keep your `model(NSObject Type)Class` for Making some DB call, Request call to server. Keep `View` Classes code Like `UIView` separately and put the Code inside `Controller class` only which needed to control the Logic of App.

[Here is the Link which explain The `MVC` Architecture.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

I hope it clears to you.

Comment: @it's a humble request, suppose my explaination is not right please intimate me rather doing any downVote.it would be helpful.and try to put some commenting for the downVote...

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've implemented looks like this. I'll accept iOS-Developer's answer though since it set me on the right track.

```
//*********************
//ReadViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GeneralModel.h"

@interface ReadViewController : UIViewController {
    GeneralModel *generalModel;
}

@end
//*********************


//*********************
//ReadViewController.m
#import "ReadViewController.h"

@interface ReadViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReadViewController

NSArray *allProperties;

- (void) getProperties {
    generalModel = [[GeneralModel alloc] init];
    allProperties = [generalModel getProperties];
    NSLog(@"ALLPROPERTIES: %@", allProperties);
    [generalModel release];
}
//**********************


//**********************
//GeneralModel.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface GeneralModel : NSObject {

}
-(NSArray *) getProperties;
@end
//**********************


//**********************
//GeneralModel.m
#import "GeneralModel.h"

@implementation GeneralModel

- (NSArray *) getProperties {
    NSLog(@"Start getProperties");
    NSArray *someProperties;
//Some nice code goes here for getting a lot of nice properties from somewhere else.
    return someProperties
    NSLog(@"End getProperties");
}
//***********************
```

Comment: I suggest you use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead of manual memory management. It saves a lot of time and is definitely the way forward. Also, you seem to have referenced `sqlite3.h`. You might want to consider using Core Data (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) instead, which is the Apple-provided default database solution for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If this method Going to be used in many places in Application then in this case you should treat it as Global method and try to put this method in separate class may be type of NSObject Class.

```
@interface Utility :NSobject
- (void) getProperties
@end

@implementation Utility

- (void) getProperties {
    NSLog(@"Start getProperties");
    //SOME CODE
    NSLog(@"End getProperties");
}
@end
```

Here Whenever you need that methods you just need to create the Object of Utility Class can access it easily wherever it needed.like

in ReadViewController just make object and access in this way

```
Utility * obje = [Utility  alloc]init];
[obje getProperties  ];
```